# Need help referencing another excel sheet cell based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to build a workbook with 4 tabs for a small business.

There are 3 locations, and the first tab will be a scorecard of sorts.

So, on the first tab (named scorecard) I have something like

```
Date: August 30, 2017
loc            sales
location 1       500
location 2       500
location 3       500
```

the other 3 tabs are names loc1,loc2,loc3 and each one is set up for 31 days going vertically like:

```
1 500
2 500
3 500
```

what I want is for on the scorecard sheet, to be able to select a cell on say loc1 sheet based on the date. I know how to reference other sheets, I just don't know how to reference a specific cell on the second sheet bases on the date entered in the first sheet.

So say today, August 30, it would pull =loc!1B30 for sales, =loc!C30 for customer count etc

I hope that makes sense, if not I can try and explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is each cell for sales amount associated with a date? If so, you can use a "VLOOKUP" formula. Check out this page for a further explanation.

https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Using VLOOKUP, the "value" would be the cell of the date on the scorecard tab, the "table" would be the dates and sales values on the locX tab, the "index number" would be the column number in the table you select (probably 2 for you I assume if there is a date, then value), and the last portion of VLOOKUP would probably be set to false. That would be true if there were several of the same date for sales, but I doubt that from what I understand.

It would look like this:

```
 =vlookup([date cell reference],[table to look up value in],[column number in table],false)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going about that entirely the wrong way! I have it working now!